# Problema con Validación

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, validación

me han encargado una tarea, pero el problema es que no consigo que valide el formulario. Os pongo más abajo una foto con los requisitos que me piden.

Cualquier tipo de ayuda se agradece.

Un saludo y gracias.

Requisitos:

```
Nombre( máximo 15 caracteres)
Apellidos ( máximo 30 caracteres)
Correo valido
Fecha valida de nacimiento y con mayoría de edad
Ciudad ( máximo 15 caracteres)
Código postal numérico y valido
País (desplegable con listado)
Nombre de usuario ( máximo 15 y sin caracteres espaciales)
Clave ( 8 caracteres con al menos una mayúscula, número, letra y carácter especial)
```

Condiciones de registro

Deberá ponerse la casilla en rojo cuando es erróneo y mostrar ventana o mensaje de error y en amarillo cuando se pasa el cursor y se selecciona la casilla.

```js
//Aqui va la funcion creaCuenta() con las verificaciones y demás. 
            
function creaCuenta() {

    //Verificar nombre y apellido
    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    apellido = document.getElementById("apellidos").value; 
    correo = document.getElementById("correoE").value;
    fechaNac = document.getElementById("nacimiento").value; 
    ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad").value; 
    user = document.getElementById("usuario").value; 

    //Comparamos nombre y apellido si están vacíos
    if (nombre == "") {
        alert("El campo nombre no se puede quedar vacío.");
        nombre.style.background = "red";
    }

    if (apellido == "") {
        alert("El campo apellido no se puede quedar vacío.");
        nombre.style.background = "red";
    }

    //Comprobar correo
    if (correo == "") {
        alert("El correo no se puede quedar vacío."); 
    }

    //Verificar si es mayor de edad
    var fecha = document.getElementById("nacimiento");
    var edad = calcularEdad(fecha); 

    if (edad < 18) {
        alert("No puedes seguir el proceso"); 
    }

    //funcion para calcular la edad
    function calcularEdad(fecha) {
        var hoy = new Date(); 
        var cumpleaños = new Date(fecha);
        var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleaños.getFullYear();
        var mes = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleaños.getMonth();

        //Comprobacion
        if (mes < 0 || mes == 0 & hoy.getDate() < cumpleaños.getDate()) {
            edad--;
        }
        return edad;
    }

    //Comprobar ciudad
    if (ciudad == "") {
        alert("Tienes que rellenar la ciudad");
    }

    //comprobar usuario
    if(user == "") {
        alert("Tienes que poner un usuario.");
    }

}


//Accion al cargar la pagina
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("Enviar").onclick = creaCuenta;
}

/*
//Evento Invalid: Se desencadena cada vez que un formulario falla en la validación
document.formulario.addEventListener("invalid", validarTiempoReal, true);   

function validar(errorFormulario) {

//Pondrá en rojo el elemento que falle
var elemento = errorFormulario.target; 
elemento.style.background = "red";
}
*/
```

```css
/* Estilo para que el texto se alinee al centro */
h1, h3 {
    text-align: center
}

#Enviar {
    font-size: 30px; 
    margin-left: 45%; 
    margin-top: 2%
}
```

```html
<!-- Creamos el título principal -->
<h1>ESPANA FASCINANTE</h1>

<!-- Otro subtitulo -->
<h3>Formulario de registro</h3>    

<!-- Creacion del Formulario -->

<form name="formulario" id="formulario" 
autocomplete="off" action="" method="GET">

<!-- Datos basicos -->
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>QUIEN ERES</strong></legend>

    <!-- Campo de texto para nombre con maximo 15 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="nombre"><strong>Nombre:<br/> </strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="15" required></p>

    <!-- Campo de texto apellidos con maximo 30 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="apellidos"><strong>Apellidos:<br/> </strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" maxlength="30" required></p>

    <!-- Campo con email con autovalidacion -->
    <p><label for="correoE"><strong>Correo electrónico:<br/> </strong></label>
    <input type="email" name="correoE" id="correoE" required></p>

    <!-- Campo para introducir fecha de nacimiento-->
    <p><label for="date"><strong>Fecha de nacimiento:<br/> </strong></label>
    <input type="date" name="nacimiento" id="nacimiento" required></p>

</fieldset></br>

<!-- Informacion geográfica -->
<fieldset>

    <legend><strong>DE DONDE ERES</strong></legend>

    <!-- Campo de texto para ciudad con maximo 15 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="ciudad"><strong>Ciudad:<br/> </strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" maxlength="15"  required></p>

    <!-- Campo para codigo postal que solo sea numero -->
    <p><label for="codigoPostal"><strong>Codigo Postal:<br/> </strong></label>
    <input pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="codigoPostal" id="codigoPostal"
    placeholder="Introduce 5 digitos" required></p>

    <!-- Lista desplegable para buscar el pais -->
   <datalist id="pais" >

    <option value="España" id="pais1" ></option>
    <option value="Alemania" id="pais2"></option>
    <option value="Francia" id="pais3"></option>
    <option value="Italia" id="pais4"></option>
    <option value="Portugal" id="pais5"></option>

   </datalist>

   <!-- Definicion del campo Pais -->
   <p><label for="pais"><strong>País:<br/> </strong> </label>
   <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" list="pais" required></p>

</fieldset></br>

<!-- Datos de inicio de sesión -->
<fieldset>

    <legend><strong>COMO QUIERES INICIAR SESION</strong></legend>

    <!-- Campo de texto para usuario con maximo 15 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="usuario"><strong>Usuario:<br/> </strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="15" required></p>

    <!-- Campo de contraseña con minimo 8 caracteres + 
    requerimentos especiales (una mayúscula, número, letra y 
    carácter especial -- Expresiones regulares) -->
    <p><label for="password"><strong>Clave:<br/> </strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" 
    pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
    required></p>

    <!-- Revalidar la contraseña-->
    <p><label for="passwordVer"><strong>Vuelve a escribir
        la clave:<br/> </strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="passv" id="passv" 
    pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
    required></p>

</fieldset><br/>

<!-- Politica de uso + Privacidad -->
<fieldset>

    <legend><strong>CONDICIONES DE REGISTRO</strong></legend>

    <strong>Deseo recibir ofertas de ESPANA FASCINANTE</strong><br/><br/>

    <!-- Checkbox para condiciones de registro -->
    <span>
    <input type="radio" name="opcionCheck" id="dia">Una vez al día
    </span>

    <span>
    <input type="radio" name="opcionCheck" id="semana">
    Una vez a la semana
    </span>

    <span>
    <input type="radio" name="opcionCheck" id="mes">Una vez al mes
    </span>

    <br/><br/>

    <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acuerdo" id="acuerdo" required />
    Acepto el acuerdo de servicios, la declaracion de privacidad
    y el uso de cookies
    </span>

</fieldset>

<!-- Botón de envío formulario -->
<input type="submit" id="Enviar" value="Registrar" />

</form>
```

Comment: Creo que se te ha olvidado cancelar el submit

Comment: Podrías indicar si alguna de las respuesta que te dejaron más abajo te fue útil o no, haciendo clic en el ticket.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que cuando defines las variables para manejar los `input` desde `JS`, estas diciéndoles que estas sean igual al `value` del `input` y no al `input` en si. Por lo que tus variables serian igual al valor del `input`. Entonces cuando quieres cambiar el estilo no lo haces al `input` si no al `string` que asignaste. por eso no cambia de color.

Cambie un poco tu código para que veas como sería. Por lo menos para que puedas avanzar.

```js
//Aqui va la funcion creaCuenta() con las verificaciones y demás. 

function creaCuenta() {

  //Verificar nombre y apellido
  nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
  apellido = document.getElementById("apellidos");
  correo = document.getElementById("correoE");
  fechaNac = document.getElementById("nacimiento");
  ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad");
  user = document.getElementById("usuario");

  //Comparamos nombre y apellido si están vacíos
  if (nombre.value == "") {
    alert("El campo nombre no se puede quedar vacío.");
    nombre.style.background = "red";
  }

  if (apellido.value == "") {
    alert("El campo apellido no se puede quedar vacío.");
    nombre.style.background = "red";
  }

  //Comprobar correo
  if (correo.value == "") {
    alert("El correo no se puede quedar vacío.");
  }

  //Verificar si es mayor de edad
  var fecha = document.getElementById("nacimiento");
  var edad = calcularEdad(fecha);

  if (edad < 18) {
    alert("No puedes seguir el proceso");
  }

  //funcion para calcular la edad
  function calcularEdad(fecha) {
    var hoy = new Date();
    var cumpleaños = new Date(fecha);
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleaños.getFullYear();
    var mes = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleaños.getMonth();

    //Comprobacion
    if (mes < 0 || mes == 0 & hoy.getDate() < cumpleaños.getDate()) {
      edad--;
    }
    return edad;
  }

  //Comprobar ciudad
  if (ciudad.value == "") {
    alert("Tienes que rellenar la ciudad");
  }

  //comprobar usuario
  if (user.value == "") {
    alert("Tienes que poner un usuario.");
  }

}


//Accion al cargar la pagina
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Enviar").onclick = creaCuenta;
}

/*
//Evento Invalid: Se desencadena cada vez que un formulario falla en la validación
document.formulario.addEventListener("invalid", validarTiempoReal, true);   

function validar(errorFormulario) {

//Pondrá en rojo el elemento que falle
var elemento = errorFormulario.target; 
elemento.style.background = "red";
}
*/
```

```css
/* Estilo para que el texto se alinee al centro */

h1,
h3 {
  text-align: center
}

#Enviar {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 2%
}

input:hover, input:focus {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- Creamos el título principal -->
<h1>ESPANA FASCINANTE</h1>

<!-- Otro subtitulo -->
<h3>Formulario de registro</h3>

<!-- Creacion del Formulario -->

<form name="formulario" id="formulario" autocomplete="off" action="" method="GET">

  <!-- Datos basicos -->
  <fieldset>
    <legend><strong>QUIEN ERES</strong></legend>

    <!-- Campo de texto para nombre con maximo 15 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="nombre"><strong>Nombre:<br/> </strong> </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="15" required></p>

    <!-- Campo de texto apellidos con maximo 30 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="apellidos"><strong>Apellidos:<br/> </strong> </label>
      <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" maxlength="30" required></p>

    <!-- Campo con email con autovalidacion -->
    <p><label for="correoE"><strong>Correo electrónico:<br/> </strong></label>
      <input type="email" name="correoE" id="correoE" required></p>

    <!-- Campo para introducir fecha de nacimiento-->
    <p><label for="date"><strong>Fecha de nacimiento:<br/> </strong></label>
      <input type="date" name="nacimiento" id="nacimiento" required></p>

  </fieldset>
  </br>

  <!-- Informacion geográfica -->
  <fieldset>

    <legend><strong>DE DONDE ERES</strong></legend>

    <!-- Campo de texto para ciudad con maximo 15 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="ciudad"><strong>Ciudad:<br/> </strong> </label>
      <input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" maxlength="15" required></p>

    <!-- Campo para codigo postal que solo sea numero -->
    <p><label for="codigoPostal"><strong>Codigo Postal:<br/> </strong></label>
      <input pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="codigoPostal" id="codigoPostal" placeholder="Introduce 5 digitos" required></p>

    <!-- Lista desplegable para buscar el pais -->
    <datalist id="pais">

    <option value="España" id="pais1" ></option>
    <option value="Alemania" id="pais2"></option>
    <option value="Francia" id="pais3"></option>
    <option value="Italia" id="pais4"></option>
    <option value="Portugal" id="pais5"></option>

   </datalist>

    <!-- Definicion del campo Pais -->
    <p><label for="pais"><strong>País:<br/> </strong> </label>
      <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" list="pais" required></p>

  </fieldset>
  </br>

  <!-- Datos de inicio de sesión -->
  <fieldset>

    <legend><strong>COMO QUIERES INICIAR SESION</strong></legend>

    <!-- Campo de texto para usuario con maximo 15 caracteres -->
    <p><label for="usuario"><strong>Usuario:<br/> </strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="15" required></p>

    <!-- Campo de contraseña con minimo 8 caracteres + 
    requerimentos especiales (una mayúscula, número, letra y 
    carácter especial -- Expresiones regulares) -->
    <p><label for="password"><strong>Clave:<br/> </strong></label>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required></p>

    <!-- Revalidar la contraseña-->
    <p><label for="passwordVer"><strong>Vuelve a escribir
        la clave:<br/> </strong></label>
      <input type="password" name="passv" id="passv" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required></p>

  </fieldset><br/>

  <!-- Politica de uso + Privacidad -->
  <fieldset>

    <legend><strong>CONDICIONES DE REGISTRO</strong></legend>

    <strong>Deseo recibir ofertas de ESPANA FASCINANTE</strong><br/><br/>

    <!-- Checkbox para condiciones de registro -->
    <span>
    <input type="radio" name="opcionCheck" id="dia">Una vez al día
    </span>

    <span>
    <input type="radio" name="opcionCheck" id="semana">
    Una vez a la semana
    </span>

    <span>
    <input type="radio" name="opcionCheck" id="mes">Una vez al mes
    </span>

    <br/><br/>

    <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acuerdo" id="acuerdo" required />
    Acepto el acuerdo de servicios, la declaracion de privacidad
    y el uso de cookies
    </span>

  </fieldset>

  <!-- Botón de envío formulario -->
  <input type="submit" id="Enviar" value="Registrar" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

He hecho los cambios que me menciona Luis más arriba y he conseguido que salga rojo cuando es erróneo, y amarillo al pasar el cursor, cuando lo pones bien, se queda la casilla en blanco.

Solo me quedaría ahora lo que es Validar la fecha y la edad del supuesto usuario.

Gracias por la ayuda.